# Given that Martin Luther King Jr is so revered in the US, why is there no tag for him on Christianity.SE?

Tags: discussion, tags

My impression is that Christianity.SE, having hung around SE for some time, has an active readership of mostly Christians from the US. Given how I've heard how Martin Luther King Jr is revered in the US, and the UK - there is a statue of him on Westminster Cathedral, imagine my surprise when I discovered there was no tag for him on this site, which is now in alpha, not beta. I find this very surprising.

**Q. Is there some reason for this omission?**

Answer (score 2):

No particular reason. Mostly just that we haven't had many questions about him before. I think, before your question today, we've only had [one question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/6540/6071) that's actually about him, with [one other](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/69419/6071) that quotes him but isn't actually *about* him (and so arguably doesn't warrant being tagged with his name.)

I've gone ahead and made the tag. [martin-luther-king-jr](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/martin-luther-king-jr)